# Parametrization of unit varieties

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field with integral basis $\{\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n\}$. Then
$$ \Phi(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = N_{K/{\mathbb Q}}(\omega_1 X_1 + \ldots + \omega_n X_n) $$
is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ with integral coefficients, and the integral points on the affine variety
$$ \Phi(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = 1 $$
correspond to units with norm $+1$ in the ring of integers of $K$.

For quadratic extensions, this "unit variety" is defined by $X_1^2 - mX_2^2 = 1$
(a Pell conic) whenever $m \equiv 2, 3 \bmod 4$ is squarefree; for other extensions of small 
degree it is similarly easy to write down explicit equations.

It is well known that the *rational* points on the Pell conic can be parametrized. The same thing holds for general cyclic extensions: the 
[proof](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/hilbert.pdf) via Hilbert 90 that Pell conics can be parametrized generalizes easily. This suggests the following question:

**Can unit varieties of number fields be parametrized by rational functions with rational coefficients?**

Comment: Is each "unit variety" an algebraic torus, or is this only the case in dimension one? Certainly they are all algebraic groups over Q

Comment: @Daniel: The unit equations are the kernel of the Norm map from the $R_{K/\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{G}_m$ to $\mathbb{G}_m$. Indeed these are algebraic groups, and also algebraic tori, of rank one less than that of the field extension. I think that there are cases where these are not rational. If I recall correctly, a non-cyclic cubic extension of the rationals should give a non-rational surface, but I can't seem to find a reference for this (maybe it's false??).

Comment: Thanks Dror for clarifying! I think I have found a reference...

Comment: Right, I'm wrong about the cubic remark. We get a parametrisation by going up to the quadratic field and back down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Dror for pointing out a nice geometrical way to think of such varieties.
This paper shows that such varieties are not rational in general:

http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~florence/norm_one.pdf

However, any algebraic torus over a number field $K$ of dimension one or two is rational over $K$. Indeed, the case of dimension one is easy, and the case of dimension two is a theorem of Voskresenskiĭ, but algebraic tori of dimension three and above do not have to be rational over the ground field in general.